# Conceptual question on Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

today I've stumbled in a interesting question about probabilities while talking to a friend, I don't know whether here is the best place to ask, but as it involves probabilities, I'll try.

Given a set of numbers $1,\ldots,N$ as a sample space in a lottery ticket, we have to mark a subset of $M$ numbers.

Why do we have a common sense that we have better chances choosing a sparse subset of numbers instead of a contiguous subset. Isn't the probability the same, or is there deeper math involved that I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The probabilities are the same, if the Lottery Corporation does its randomization properly. What you call "common sense" is not correct. Why it is common sense is a question of psychology, not mathematics. It is akin to the (wrong) feeling that if we have tossed a die $10$ times and not gotten a $6$, then $6$ is in some sense overdue and has a higher probability than $1/6$ of occurring. It is more strongly related to the fact that people without access to a randomizing device are very poor at producing a "random" sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s.

Comment: Any given ticket (with consecutive elements or not) is equally likely.  My suspicion is that people don't buy tickets with consecutive numbers because that doesn't feel "random enough" to them.  But it's purely a psychology question, not a randomization question.

Comment: This common sense might be related to the fact that there are more ways to pick $M$ numbers so that the subset is not contiguous than there are ways to pick $M$ numbers so that it is. So people tend to think that it's more likely that the subset is sparse. But people suck in maths unfortunately

Comment: Yes, I know there's some kind of psychology in this question. @krirkrirk pointed an interesting fact, I haven't minded that there are more 'sparse' subsets than 'contiguous' ones. It's know that most people aren't aware of this, but maybe by intuition, they believe it, which turns out to be true.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of any number combination being drawn is exactly the same, assuming the lottery is fair (which it is virtually guaranteed to be). However, if you want to maximize your expected winnings, then you have to take into account how many people you split the prize with. If you choose 1,2,3,4,5,6 probably a lot of other people will choose this too so if you win you have to split the prize many ways so your expected winnings are significantly lower. So you should either choose randomly or try to figure out what number combinations are the least likely to be picked by other people.

Comment: Actually, your argument that common sense tells us to avoid simple patterns is based on the fact that commonly their senses tell people to use simple patterns. :)

Comment: In terms of purchasing strategy (which you hint at) I've always wondered about buying tickets making a block design so that you are guaranteed to match at least $k$ of the $M$ values... or any $k$ subset of the chosen $M$ appears on at least one of your tickets.  Then, what's the probability that you "accidentally" hit an extra number or two...

Comment: I seem to remember that picking numbers less than 31 was a bad idea because birthdays are often chosen and you'd be sharing with others. Not sure how you'd go about proving that though if it is true. Personally I'd share and get by with a bit less.

Comment: @Karl Yes I've seen Pennsylvania lottery results where they give the winning numbers along with the number of winners of each prize level. When a number 12 or less does not show up, the number of winners at the lower levels significantly decreases. So it seems the "birthday effect" is real and significant.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that all subsets of size $M$ have the same probability,
the intuition that some subsets are 'rare', or 'suspicious' is not
entirely foolish.

Partly, this has to do with the ever-present doubt whether the lottery
is really fair. What patterns would provide evidence of unfairness.
Suppose we wonder whether the $N$ numbered balls are properly mixed
before drawing. One possible consequence of improper mixing would
be for the numbers drawn all to be low numbers, say all below $N/4$,
or all of them to be high numbers, say above $3N/4$.

If we keep track of the order in which the numbers are drawn, we
could do a runs test for randomness. A very long run of numbers lower
than $N/2$ anywhere among the $M$ draws would cause a sample to 'fail' the runs test and
lead to the conclusion that the drawing mechanism isn't a random
one.

[*Note:* Suspicions have not always been unwarranted. Google 'unfair
draft lottery' to find information on pretty clearly biased
US draft lotteries during the Viet Nam War era. Before the method
of 'randomization' was refined, it seems that far too many December
birthdays were chosen early.]

Hypothesis testing often depends on picking outcomes that look
extreme assuming the null hypothesis to be false in a particular way. A simple non-lottery example
would be a test of whether a die is fair or biased in favor of 6's.
Suppose we get all 6's in ten rolls of the die. That outcome has the
same chance as any of the other $6^{10} = 60,466,176$ possible (ordered)
sequences. But, because this extreme outcome is *especially likely* for
a die biased in favor of 6's, no sensible person would believe the
die is fair.

Many--maybe most--gamblers enter a game with hopes (or suspicions) that
the allegedly random process will somehow be biased for them (or against).
Given such mind-sets, it is hard for them to believe that all of the
outcomes are really likely.

Answer (score 0):

While Bruce's explanation of possible unfairness is plausible, I think our intuition is rooted in something else, which we might think of as the fungibility of a given set of six numbers.

Suppose the lottery selection is six numbers from the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, 50\}$.  The subset $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, though no less likely in fact than $\{3, 17, 20, 31, 44, 48\}$, is nonetheless *perceived* to be less likely, because the probability that something "like" $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ (for some not altogether well-defined sense of "like") is less likely than something "like" $\{3, 17, 21, 30, 44, 48\}$.  Probably the only thing "like" $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ in most people's minds is itself, whereas many subsets are "like" $\{3, 17, 20, 34, 41, 48\}$.

For instance, I wonder how many readers noticed that I made small changes in the more random-looking set, each time I referred to it.

This notion of fungibility is related to information-theoretical notions of entropy and Komolgorov complexity, and those notions might be used to express the fungibility, but I'm not sure that human psychology can really be accurately reduced to those notions.  It's probably best, in my opinion, to leave it vague and think of it as a general notion of fungibility.